# 404 Error after URL update

Tags: php, 404-error, apache, phpmyadmin

I changed our company domain name and now all i get is a 404 error.

I have updated the option table in phpmyadmin as well as updated apache2 conf.

Where else do I need to change the info for this to work?

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName newdomainname.com
    ServerAlias www.newdomainname.com
    Redirect / https://newdomainname.com/


</VirtualHost>


<VirtualHost *:443>

ServerAdmin .it@gmail.com
ServerName newdomainname.com/

DocumentRoot /var/www/testIVMC/
SSLEngine on
SSLCertificateFile /cloudflare/ivmcMaster.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /cloudflare/ivmcMaster.key

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/vik.com_error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/vik.com_access.log combined

<Directory /var/www/testIVMC/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
        Allow from all
</Directory>

    <FilesMatch \.php$>
        SetHandler "proxy:unix:/run/php/php8.2-fpm.sock|fcgi://127.0.0.1:9000"
    </FilesMatch>
</VirtualHost>
```

Folder structure

var->
www->
testIVMC

Answer (score 0):

You might have already done this, but while logged into the admin of your site, go to **Settings > General** and then review the urls in **WordPress Address (URL)** and **Site Address (URL)**. If they do not read with the new domain name, then they need to be updated.

Once you have the correct urls in place, visit **Settings > Permalinks** and refresh them. Usually do that by making a change, saving, then changing it back. and saving again. You can also do this via command line with WP CLI if available. Usually if a site is going to a 404, this is the go-to solution.